# Passing data to a function inside ngAfterViewInit() - Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new to codding, I am created a canvas in angular, and I am trying to pass data 
That I am receiving from my server to my function inside `ngAfterViewInit()`.

The thing is when I am hard coding the values that I want to pass it works great,
But if I passing this data after I received it from my server it throw a `undefined` error to the values inside the `ngAfterViewInit()`.

I am trying to pass those values :

```
seatsNum: number
rowsNum : number
```

To those :

```
  var numberOfSeats = this.seatsNum
  var numberOfRows = this.rowsNum
```

This the full code:

```
import { Component, Directive, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, Input, Renderer, ContentChild, ViewChildren, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ManageShowsService } from '../../services/shows-mananger.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '../../../../node_modules/@angular/router';
import { Show } from '../../models/show.model';
import { DomSanitizer } from '../../../../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-seat-selection',
  templateUrl: './seat-selection.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./seat-selection.component.scss']
})
export class SeatSelectionComponent {
  show: any
  tempOrderArrey = new Array()
  orderSeatsClinet = []    
  selectedSeatsClient = []
  selectedSeatsServer = [{ "id": 5 }, { "id": 19 }] 

  seatsNum: number
  rowsNum : number


  cX: number // X click cordinates
  cY: number // Y click cordinates  


  @ViewChild('canvas') canvasRef:ElementRef;
    private canvas: any;
    @Input('size') size: number;
    @Input('color') color: string;
    @Input() width: number;
    @Input() height: number;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef,
                private renderer: Renderer,
                private showService: ManageShowsService,
                private route: ActivatedRoute,
                private sanitzizer: DomSanitizer) {



    }

    sanitize(url:string){
        return this.sanitzizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('http://localhost:3000/' + url);
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.showService.getShowById(this.route.snapshot.params['id'])
            .subscribe(data => {
                console.log(data)
                this.seatsNum = data.showsHall[0].rows
                this.rowsNum = data.showsHall[0].seats

                this.show = {
                    "hallName": data.showsHall[0].hallName,
                    "movieName": data.movie[0].movieName,
                    "movieImg": data.movie[0].movieImg,
                    "takenSeats": data.takenSeats,
                    "_id": data._id,
                    "showDate": data.showDate,
                    "showStartTime": data.showStartTime,
                    "showEndTime": data.showEndTime,

                }
                console.log("form ts" + this.seatsNum, this.rowsNum)
            })



    }






    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.canvas = this.canvasRef.nativeElement;
        this.canvas.width = 550;
        this.canvas.height = 500;
        this.draw();

    }



    draw() {

      var ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.font = "15px Arial";
      var seats = []                                    
      var tempOrderArrey = []                        
      var orderSeatsClinet = []                     
      var selectedSeatsClient = []                    
      var selectedSeatsServer = this.selectedSeatsServer
      var numberOfSeats = this.seatsNum
      var numberOfRows = this.rowsNum
      console.log("from js" + numberOfSeats, numberOfRows)
      var counter = 0    
      function make_base() {
        var base_image = new Image();
            base_image.src = ('../../../assets/img/screen2.png');
            base_image.onload = function () {
                ctx.drawImage(base_image, 75, -110);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need **`ngAfterViewInit`** here, you are making an asynchronous call, so it takes a bit of time.

To fix this, you can call your function once you get the data inside the **`subscribe()`** as follows,

```
this.showService.getShowById(this.route.snapshot.params['id'])
.subscribe(data => {
   ...////your logic and then
     this.canvas = this.canvasRef.nativeElement;
     this.canvas.width = 550;
     this.canvas.height = 500;
     this.draw();
}
```

Comment: I dont have any idea why the guys downvoted it works great, thank you!